# How to make React app background color have infinite height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make the entire backgroundColor to a React application be set to black. This is proving complicated though. I have set the main App div to have a height of 100% ( and then a child component to have 100% height as well with a black background. This didn't work so then I tried setting the main App div to have a height of 100vh. This makes the full view port have a black background but the page's background is white when scrolling down. I have shared a screenshot below to show what I did. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image]

This is what is happening but this is not what I want. I want the whole thing to have a black background even when infinitely scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Add the background color to `body or html` in `index.css` instead of adding the style on the div.

Comment: Just add `html, body{height:100%;}`. then `heigh:100%` will be applied to your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a background color to the body or html instead

```
body {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: But what if we want to change body's bg color dynamically? Like when theme changes.